# A short story about a family on their way to see aliens

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, aliens

This was a short story about a family on their way to see aliens and a majority of the story is set in the car while the family discusses it. The mother is concerned that they will act like 'cavemen' while the kid is excited to see them. Once they get there it's revealed the aliens are actually humans with the kid saying 'One was pink and the other brown'.

I can't recall any other details other than that one phrase and the general basis of the story. Though it was assigned as reading material when I was in school (I'm from Australia).The author was male but I can't recall his name.

Comment: Welcome to [scifi.se]! Can you take a look at [this guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/58193) and [edit] in anything else? For example, do you know when you read it? Also don't forget to [register your account](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/44557/345161).

Comment: You didn't say but let me guess: the family in the car are non-humans? The mother is afraid **who** will act like cavemen, her kids, or the strange beings they are going to see? Is the story set on another planet? Are the pink and brown humans honored guests, or are they captives in a zoo?

Comment: Yes sorry, the family in the car are aliens, the mother is afraid the ''aliens'' who are humans will act like cavemen. It is set on another planet and the humans are guests. I believe they speak in front of a big crowd where the family is heading but I'm not 100% sure on that detail.

Comment: I vaguely remember this one.

Comment: @OrganicMarble Do you happen to remember anything else I might not have added?